# CriteriaBuilder API. IN clause query

Tags: java, jpa, jpa-2.0, criteria, criteria-api

There is a database schema, as shown below.
[image]

I have a collection `Collection<String> sportCodes` of `codes` from the `sport` table.

I can build a predicate...

```
private Collection<String> sportCodes;

private Predicate searchBySportsPredicate(Root<PlaygroundEntity> root) {
    return root.join(PlaygroundEntity_.specializations).get(SportEntity_.code).in(sportCodes);
}
```

...and get the `PlaygroundEntity` with a set of `sport codes` included in the collection `sportCodes`.

**How I can do it vice versa?**

i.e. to build predicate like this...

```
(sportCodes).in(root.join(PlaygroundEntity_.specializations).get(SportEntity_.code))
```

...and get the `PlaygroundEntity` with a set of `sport codes` that includes a collection `sportCodes`.

I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: You mean that have all sports codes ?

Comment: @Antoniossss, sorry, I did not understand what you mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I spent 3 days on this issue, and the solution was too simple:

```
private Predicate searchBySportsPredicate(Root<PlaygroundEntity> root, CriteriaBuilder cb) {
    Collection<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String sportCode : sportCodes) {
        predicates.add(
                cb.equal(root.join(PlaygroundEntity_.specializations).get(SportEntity_.code), sportCode)
        );
    }
    return cb.and(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[0]));
}
```

**IMPORTANT**

**It doesn't work:**

```
private Predicate searchBySportsPredicate(Root<PlaygroundEntity> root, CriteriaBuilder cb) {
    List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>(sportCodes.size());
    Path<String> codePath = root.join(PlaygroundEntity_.specializations).get(SportEntity_.code)
    for (String sportCode : sportCodes) {
        predicates.add(cb.equal(codePath, sportCode));
    }
    return cb.and(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[0]));
}
```

Hope it helps someone.